# Python Flask Как сделать, чтобы на фоне постоянно шла проверка данных из Базы Данных?

Tags: python, многопоточность, sqlite, flask

Нужно :
1 - Нажать на кнопку
2 - Запускается функция которая проверяет, если в БД параметр x<10, то каждую секунду x+=1
3 - И тут же перенаправляет на главную страницу return redirect("/main")
4 - На фоне всё ещё идёт x+=1, пока не накопится x=10

Как у меня :
1 - Нажимаю на кнопку
2 - Запускается функция которая проверяет, если в БД параметр x<10, то каждую секунду x+=1
3 - В течение 10 секунд, страница "висит" в загрузке
4 - Через 10 секунд перенаправляет на главную страницу return redirect("/main")

```
@application.route('/add', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def add():
    add_one() #ЕСЛИ УБРАТЬ ЭТО ОШИБКА (НИЖЕ)
    thread1 = Thread(target=add_one)
    thread1.start()
    thread1.join()
    return redirect("/main")

def add_one():
    while current_user.x_current < current_user.x_max:
        current_user.x_current += 1
        db.session.commit()
        sleep(1)
```

while current_user.x_current < current_user.x_max:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'x_current'

**Резюмирую вопрос :** Как сделать перенаправление redirect("/main"), ДО того как функция завершит свой расчёт?

Comment: `thread1.join()` Присоединяет поток к главному (То есть программа будет ждать завершения потока) уберите это и программа не будет ждать

Comment: Убрал, всё равно пока 10 секунд не пройдёт (по умолчанию x=0), перенаправление return redirect("/main") не происходит

Comment: + `add_one()` вот это надо убрать вызов функции не нужно делать отдельно

Comment: Тут моя невнимателньость, верно. Спасибо! Но
Теперь функция вообще не запускается
    while current_user.x_current < current_user.x_max:
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'x_current'

Comment: Вы должны передавать объект пользователя в качестве аргумента в функцию `Thread(target=add_one, args=(current_user, ))` и `def add_one(user):`

Comment: Странно, но ошибка остаётся та же, т.е. к объекту он правильно обращается. Сейчас читаю, проблема в sqlite "В SQLite ограничена многопоточность — единовременное выполнение нескольких процессов. Одновременно читать из базы могут несколько процессов, а писать в нее по умолчанию — только один. "